# Java BigDecimal difference

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I wanted to see if anyone can explain why the following code works with valueOf but not others.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal; 
public class Change {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     double a = 4.00d;
     double b = 3.10d;
     BigDecimal a1 = new BigDecimal(a);
     BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(b);
     BigDecimal diff = a1.subtract(b1);
     System.out.println("Double difference");
     System.out.println(diff);

     float c = 4.00f;
     float d = 3.10f;
     BigDecimal a2 = new BigDecimal(c);
     BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(d);
     BigDecimal diff2 = a2.subtract(b2);
     System.out.println("Float difference");
     System.out.println(diff2);

     System.out.println("Valueof Difference");
     System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(4.00).subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(3.10)));

   }
 }
```

The output looks like:

```
>java Change
 Double difference
  0.899999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
 Float difference
  0.900000095367431640625
 Valueof Difference
 0.9
```

My question is: What does valueOf() do to get the precision?
Is there any other way of getting the correct result without rounding off to the 2 digits manually?

thanks,

Comment: you can look at adding the MathContext parameter to your BigDecimal constructor, if you want to play around with the precision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the source code for BigDecimal, it does:

```
public static BigDecimal valueOf(double val) {
    // Reminder: a zero double returns '0.0', so we cannot fastpath
    // to use the constant ZERO.  This might be important enough to
    // justify a factory approach, a cache, or a few private
    // constants, later.
    return new BigDecimal(Double.toString(val));
}
```

From its JavaDoc:

> Translates a double into a BigDecimal,
>   using the double's canonical string
>   representation provided by the
>   Double.toString(double) method.
>
> Note: This is generally the preferred way to
>   convert a double (or float) into a
>   BigDecimal, as the value returned is
>   equal to that resulting from
>   constructing a BigDecimal from the
>   result of using
>   Double.toString(double).

Because of floating-point representation, a double value is not exactly what you set it as. However, during String representation, it rounds off what it displays. (All of the rules are on it's [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29)).

Furthermore, because of this rounding, if you did:

`BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(4.00000000000000000000000000000000001));`

you would get the wrong value. (d == 4.0)

So, it's pretty much always better to initialize these with strings.

Comment: You are absolutely right. valueOf(4.00000000000000000001) doesn't work. Learnt something new today :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The valueOf works because it calls Double.toString. from the Javadoc:

> ```
> public static BigDecimal valueOf(double val)
>
>     Translates a double into a BigDecimal, using the double's
> ```
>
> canonical string representation
>   provided by the
>   Double.toString(double) method.

When you pass a double into the BigDecimal constructor, the constructor takes the floating-point value and reproduces it exactly. The toString code finds an approximation for the floating point value.

In case you didn't notice, using System.out.println() to show a floating point number doesn't show the same results as if you wrap the floating point number in a BigDecimal first (using the BigDecimal constructor that takes a double).

Answer (score 1):

`BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` first does a conversion from double to String, then String to BigDecimal.

In the first case, you're starting with a double or float, converting to BigDecimal, calculating the difference.  In the second case, you're starting with double or float, converting to a String, *then* converting to BigDecimal, then calculating the difference.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29):

`public static BigDecimal valueOf(double val)`

> Translates a double into a BigDecimal,
>   using the double's canonical string
>   representation provided by the
>   Double.toString(double) method. Note:
>   This is generally the preferred way to
>   convert a double (or float) into a
>   BigDecimal, as the value returned is
>   equal to that resulting from
>   constructing a BigDecimal from the
>   result of using
>   Double.toString(double).

I think this answers both of your questions.

Cheers,